# Injective or Surjective and Same Dimension Implies Vector Space Isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Just wanted to quickly work out the following two facts, since I couldn't find simple proofs quickly on the internet:
Suppose $\operatorname{dim}(V) = \operatorname{dim}(W) = n$.

1. If $T:V \to W$ is surjective and linear, it is an isomorphism.
2. IF $T:V \to W$ is injective and linear, it is an isomorphism.

Proof of 1.

Suppose $T(v_1) = T(v_2)$. Then for a basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of $V$, 
$$T(v_1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iT(e_i) = T(v_2) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} T(e_i).$$

Now since $T$ is surjective, $S:= \{T(e_i)\}_{i=1}^{n}$ spans $W$. Since $S$ has $n$ members and $\operatorname{dim}(W) = n$, it is a basis. Thus, since representations in a basis are unique, $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. Moving backwards in linearity, this implies $v_1=v_2$.

Proof of 2.

Similarly, if $T$ is injective, $S$ is L.I. of size $n$ and thus forms a basis, so working backwards in the linearity again, we get a $v$ so that $T(v) = w$.

Comment: I think you should name youre base $e_1,\dots,e_n$ instead of $v_1,\dots,v_n$ to make more clear you proof. For the proof of 1 and 2, maybe you could use the rank theorem...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Sure, works just as well since the kernel is trivial

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from the [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), saying that
$$
\dim (im (T))+\dim (\ker (T))=\dim V.
$$
If $T$ is injective, then $\dim(\ker(T)=0$, so that $\dim im (T)=n=\dim W$,
and $im(T)\subseteq W$, hence $im(T)=W$. Similarly for $T$ surjective.