# Checking Finite Field Automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

My book contains the proof of the following claim:

> Let $F$ be a finite field with characteristic p. Show that $F^p = F$

They construct a morphism $\phi: F \rightarrow F^p$ that sends $x \mapsto x^p$. The check this is a homomorphism, that it is one-to-one, and its onto. I followed most of the proof, except for checking surjection. They write one line:

> Since F is finite, $\phi$ is onto.

Why is this true?

Comment: This follows from the rank-nullity theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722921/injective-or-surjective-and-same-dimension-implies-vector-space-isomorphism).

Comment: @Dietrich $F$ is not a vector space, so how would this work? I mean I see Ker $\phi$ is zero so dim(Im($\phi$)) = dim F.

Comment: @yoshi $F$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over itself and $F^p$ is a subspace.  Actually, I guess the fact that $F^p$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication isn't clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $F^p \subseteq F$, then $\#(F^p) \leq \#F$.  Since $\phi: F \to F^p$ is injective, then $\#F \leq \#(F^p)$, so $\#(F^p) = \#F$.  Since these are finite sets, then $F^p = F$.  An injective map from a finite set to itself must also be surjective.

Comment: I have never seen the # or $\leq$ notation in relation to $F$. Could you define these or point me to a wiki?

Comment: $\#F$ just means the number of elements in $F$, aka its cardinality.  It's also sometimes written $|F|$.

Comment: I'm almost there, why is $F^p \subseteq F$ true?

Comment: $F^p$ is the set of all elements of $F$ that are $p^\text{th}$ powers: $F^p = \{a \in F : a = b^p \text{ for some } b \in F\}$.  So $F^p$ is a subset by definition.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a direct proof that $\phi$ is surjective.

Let $F$ have $q$ elements. Then $a^q = a$ for all $a \in F$ because of Lagrange's theorem applied to $F^{\times}$.

Since $q$ is a power of $p$, we have $q=tp$ and so $a=a^q=(a^t)^p \in F^p$.