# For manifolds of the same dimension, are submersions equivalent to immersions?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, continuity, manifolds

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. Immersions and submersions are defined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Hzw.png).

1. Let $A$ and $B$ be manifolds with the same dimension $d$, and let $G: A \to B$ be a smooth map. I think that for each $p \in A$, $G$ is a submersion at $p$ if and only if $G$ is an immersion at $p$ [because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722921/injective-or-surjective-and-same-dimension-implies-vector-space-isomorphism) $G_{*,p}$ is a homomorphism of vector spaces of the same finite dimension $d$.

**Is this correct? If so, then I have 2 follow-up questions.**

2. Can we restate [Remark 8.12 of the inverse function theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJx7Q.png) as follows?

   > $F$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$ if and only if any of two equivalent conditions hold:
   >
   > - $F$ is a submersion at $p$,
   > - $F$ is an immersion at $p$.
3. In this question [What does it take for a smooth homeomorphism to be a diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832344/what-does-it-take-for-a-smooth-homeomorphism-to-be-a-diffeomorphism), can we say submersion instead of immersion given that [homeomorphism of smooth manifolds implies same dimension, as with diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298439/does-homeomorphism-of-smooth-manifolds-imply-the-same-dimension)?

   - In some ways, I think one would expect immersion since what it takes for a smooth topological embedding to be a smooth embedding, as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297560/equivalent-definitions-for-smooth-embedding), is being an immersion.
   - I was actually surprised to see immersion instead of submersion. Since submersions are open maps, I initially thought of submersion as the smooth analogue for "open map", in the sense that just as we have, for a bijective continuous map $g$ of topological spaces, that $g^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is open, I thought that we would have, for the $f$ in [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832344/what-does-it-take-for-a-smooth-homeomorphism-to-be-a-diffeomorphism), $f^{-1}$ is smooth if and only if $f$ is a submersion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct on all three points.

The differential is a map between tangent spaces. If both tangent spaces have the same (finite) dimension, then an injective map is also a surjective map and is thus an isomorphism.

A local diffeomorphism *between manifolds of the same dimension* is indeed just an immersion or a submersion, as injectivity, surjectivity, and being an isomorphism on the level of tangent spaces are all equivalent.

If we have a smooth homeomorphism, your linked answer shows that it is a diffeomorphism if and only if it is an immersion. We know that a homeomorphism must be a map between manifolds of the same dimension, so here immersion is equivalent to submersion.

Comment: Oh right so now that I know that [homeomorphisms like diffeomorphisms imply the same dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298439/does-homeomorphism-of-smooth-manifolds-imply-the-same-dimension), we can simply replace immersion for submersion? Thanks!

Comment: @SeleneAuckland Yup, given a smooth map between equal dimension manifolds, any time you see “immersion” feel free to say “submersion” or “local diffeomorphism” instead.